# Is there any java solution to shorten the time of binary tree preorder traversal?

Tags: java, binary-tree, preorder

When I solve the question of binary tree postorder traversal first time, I only use one stack to store the node, and use one List as the result. So the time complexity is obviously N^2. But if use 2 stacks, the time complexity can be simplify to N.

As for the preorder traversal, I think using one stack is enough. But my solution running time is still stay in the mid-level.

So is there any solution to improve it? 
Below is my code:

```
public class Solution {
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {

        Stack<TreeNode> nodes = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (root == null)
            return result;
        nodes.push(root);

        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode temp = nodes.pop();
            result.add(temp.val);

            if (temp.right != null) {
                nodes.push(temp.right);
            }
            if (temp.left != null) {
                nodes.push(temp.left);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a linked list for the result.

Comment: You mean, use a LinkedList to store the final result instead of an ArrayList?

Comment: I have try and it seems has a little improvement. But can you give me some  more detailed explanation. I appreciate it!

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what time you got and what time you want to achieve. Are you measuring the time of this particular method or there is something beside it?

Comment: The answer to why the linked list is faster is in the Javadoc. *O(1)* insertion performance. I don't see much else that you could improve in the code. You don't say what 'mid-level' means, but either it is *O(N)* or it isn't.

Comment: @EJP Are you aware that ArrayList has amortized O(1) on appending to the end? Also if you set the right initial capacity, ArrayList will outperform LinkedList in this case. Also, using `Stack` as stack is wrong, it's backed by Vector that is synchronized and thus less fast comparing to  `LinkedList` (which implements `Deque` interface).

Comment: @Aivean I'm familiar with the Javadoc. *O(1)* is better than 'amortized *O(1)*' whichever way you look at it. He hasn't set the right inital capacity.